# HQL Query to select a list with any param from the displayed lists

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

I have a search form containing 4 dropdown lists
and I want to create an HQL Query that search for the object list depending on the values selected in those dropdown lists 
I hope that I was clear ><

like :

```
private static final String QUERY_SEARCH_USERS  = "SELECT u FROM User where param = ... ";
```

or I don't know how it should be ^^'

Is it possible ?

Comment: What is your doubt? You are not able to do the HQL query?

Comment: yes sir this is the problem , i didn't know how to do it

Comment: What you already tried?

Comment: private static final String QUERY_FIND_BY_id  = " FROM User u WHERE u.id= :param1";

Comment: but for this one the required value must have the id as input and what i want to do is to make that query accept any value as input to search the user datas

Comment: SELECT u FROM User WHERE id IS NULL  OR id= :param1 AND u.name IS NULL OR u.name = :param2" ; ... etc is this query correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct HQL/JPQL query:

```
SELECT u FROM User u 
WHERE u.id IS NULL OR u.id = :param1 AND u.name IS NULL OR u.name = :param2
```